# Does ffmpeg support encoding of raw video sequence to raw Theora Packets/Elementary bits tream

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg-theora

I have a query regarding using ffmpeg to encode a raw video(yuv sequence) to Raw Theora packets,
i.e. some kind of 'elementary bit-stream' without the Ogg container.

I am able to use ffmpeg to encode a raw video to Ogg theora bit stream, but i need to obtain a Theora bit stream with Raw Theora packets with no Ogg container header/

1) How can i achieve this?

2)If not using ffmpeg, then is there any other way/solution/tool to obtain what i need to get?

Thank you.

-AD.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and think it will do what you're looking for; I can tell it's not in an Ogg container but haven't found a good way to play it back.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -vcodec libtheora -f rawvideo outputfile
```